# Rewrite same URL structure to two differents PHP scripts

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-headers

My site uses URLs like `example.de/user1` or `example.de/project33`, which can be rewritten by an .htaccess-file.

The string after the slash is choosen by a user.

My problem is, that some URLs are user profile links and should be rewritten to `profile.php?id=...` and some URLs are project-links, which should be rewritten to `project.php...`

How can you handle it?

I thought about a HTTP header, which trigger a rewriteCondition (like -l, -f, -d etc...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no way to determine the appropriate target just by looking at the URL alone, you are going to need a dispatcher-style script to which you redirect all those requests, and that script then takes the decision for the final redirect towards `profile.php` or `project.php`. Can't happen in `mod_rewrite` otherwise, as it does not have any knowledge of your custom-URL database.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually testing whether the string after the slash is a user or a project, you'd need something else to let mod_rewrite know which is which, because you could potentially have a username the same as a project name. Something like:

```
http://example.de/u/user1
http://example.de/p/project33
```

And so the rules would make sure to match against the `u` or `p` (or whatever you choose to make them:

```
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ /project.php?id=$1 [L]
```